# Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.1 from 14.04, no desktop appears

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade

I just upgraded our machine from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.1.  After the upgrade, the desktop no longer opens.  I just got to a black screen.

Also, when I tried to run sudo apt followed by anything, I got the following error:

```
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

Any help is great appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Were you able to fix?

Comment: @CentAu Yeah, the answer below fixed it for me.  After downloading/re-installing the package, I updated and upgraded again, and now everything seems to be working.

Comment: @ShawnFahl If the below answer worked for you, accept it as the best answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04.1 I got the exact same problem. Just start your Ubuntu and press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to enter on console and then download and re-install the package `libstdc++6_5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb` via `dpkg -i` :

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/259210936/libstdc++6_5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

After that `apt-get` works fine, but I got some errors (due to mySQL and another installed libc). I try to remove those via `apt-get remove` which returns an error. Then I just run the command suggested by `apt-get` and now everything works fine.

Found the solution here: [Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 dependency issues](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/init-system-helpers/+bug/1572903)

Comment: I shorten the URL into http://goo.gl/NdPv2P, if you don't care about getting tracked by [Google](https://goo.gl/#analytics/goo.gl/NdPv2P/all_time).