# Unmet dependencies after do-release-upgrade from Lubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, upgrade, lubuntu, dependencies

I have unmet dependencies after a release upgrade very similar to:

[Upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.1 from 14.04, no desktop appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805811/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-1-from-14-04-no-desktop-appears)

I ran:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/259210936/libstdc++6_5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

(At this point I used the i368 package that fits my chipset)

This is my error now:

```
>> sudo apt-get install
...
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libstdc++-5-dev : Hängt ab von: libstdc++6 (>= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) aber 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2 ist installiert
 libstdc++6 : Hängt ab von: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) aber 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04 ist installiert
 libstdc++6-5-dbg : Hängt ab von: libstdc++6 (>= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) aber 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2 ist installiert
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie, -f zu benutzen.
```

Can anyone help me to resolve these dependencies?

Update: I can't run apt-get -f install since this would delete my core system (including apt).