# GNOME not started after failed distribution upgrade

Tags: 16.04, xorg, ubuntu-gnome

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. During upgrading, there was an error, but
it kept proceeding. The error is roughly about "sa-" something, but I
never use SpamAssassin or any mail client so I ignored it. After
upgrading and rebooting, it does not show the GNOME login screen, but
only a console. I can still log in on the console.

More information:

- On start there is an error message

  ```
  [FAILED] Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service
  ```
- `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` has an error (time omitted)

  ```
  ...
  (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
  (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
  (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
  (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
     compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 0.0.2
     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
  (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
  (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
  ...
  ```
- `pgrep gdm` shows that there is a process running: `usr/sbin/gdm3`
- `startx` wait for about a minute before printing

  ```
  xauth: timeout in locking authority file ~/.Xauthority
  ```

  and giving me a black screen. After a while (about 3 minutes) it
  gives

  ```
  xinit: giving up
  xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable

  waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

  xinit: server error
  xauth: timeout in locking authority file ~/.Xauthority
  ```

  then returned 1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you can still login to the console, do that and re-install the _desktop_. Its appears to be broken.

Comment: @George Thank you. There doesn't seem to be a package called `desktop`, did you mean [`desktop-base`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/desktop-base)? APT gives relocation error in `libapt-pkg.so.5.0`, saying some symbol is not defined in `libstdc++.so.6`. (Looks like situation is worse than I thought?)

Comment: I am referring to the default desktop that came with you installation, which should be _ubuntu-desktop_

Comment: @George Oh, so it is [this one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop). However, I still cannot run APT because of the linking error. Let me search that error online.

Comment: in the console run `sudo  apt -f install` Less I get you wrong, were you using an Ubuntu gnome or Ubuntu Xenial ?

Comment: @George I found a [duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/805811/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-1-from-14-04-no-desktop-appears)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50420/discussion-between-george-and-franklin-yu).